# Replace is not a function, no result

Tags: javascript, jquery

No result on output textarea, On the console log says, TypeError: newarr.replace is not a function, this is my jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ehillanichole/woykv768/1/

```
$('#generatebutton').on('click', function(){
        var arr = $('#input').val();
            arr = arr.replace(/\n/g, ', ');
            arr = arr.split(',');
      var newarr = []; check = 0; count = 0;
          for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
          if(check != arr[i]){ count = 1; check = arr[i]; } else { count++; }
          newarr.push(check + '.' + count);
      }
      newarr = newarr.replace(/, /g, '\n');
        $('#output').val(newarr);
});
```

My expected result is:

```
8000.1
8000.1
8000.2
8001.1
8001.2
8002.1
8003.1
8004.1
8004.2
8005.1
```

Comment: newarr is an array, which does not have a replace method

Comment: newarr is an array, which doesn't have a method named replace. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `8000.1
8000.2
8000.3`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note** : As mentioned in comments by other fellow people, newarr is an array and array does not have replace method.

You have to update your code from

```
newarr = newarr.replace(/, /g, '\n');
```

to

```
newarr = newarr.join().replace(/, /g, '\n');
```

For working version, please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/woykv768/3/

For documentation, please refer to http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp

Comment: Kinda nonsense, to encode an array as JSON, only to then replace parts of the JSON syntax again, if apparently all that is wanted here is a string containing all array elements separated by an newline character – `join` is perfectly capable of achieving that.

Comment: @CBroe - I agree with you. However, I was targeting the errors in code of OP rather than logic. Though I will consider your suggestion and add additional note for the same.

Comment: You can use `.join("\n")` directly, no need to let it use the implicit default separator character `,` just to then replace it by a newline afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble believing that the stated output is really what you want:

```
8000.1
8000.1
8000.2
...
```

Why are the first two duplicate entries supposed to have the same count, unlike all the rest of the list where each duplicate gets an incremented count? It doesn't make sense.

I actually had to trace through the code (as updated by nikhil) to see how it was generating that result, because it wasn't obvious at first glance. It's because when you generate your split array, you in effect split with `', '` and then join with `','`, so the array begins with:

```
[
    '8000'
    ' 8000'
    ' 8000',
    ...
]
```

The first one has no leading space, unlike the rest. That's why the first and second entries are being treated as different values - they are!

Any experienced programmer reading this code and looking at the output would think this is likely to be a bug, not intended behavior.

There are some other bugs too: Several of your variables are lacking `var` statements, so the code is inadvertently creating global variables. You probably meant for `check` and `count` to be declared with the `var` at the beginning of that line, but look closely: there's a semicolon in the line where it needed a comma.

Also, the indentation is inconsistent - it helps a lot to use consistent indentation.

Finally, you can simplify the code quite a bit, by removing the back-and-forth splits and joins, and by using `$.map()` to create the output array. I also threw in a `.trim()` on the input string, so it will still work correctly if there is an extra newline at the beginning or end of the `textarea`.

```
$('#generatebutton').on( 'click', function() {
    var input = $('#input').val().trim().split('\n');
    var count, last;
    var result = $.map( input, function( value ) {
        if( value != last ) {
            count = 1;  last = value;
        } else {
            count++;
        }
        return value + '.' + count;
    });
    $('#output').val( result.join('\n') );
});
```

This produces:

```
8000.1
8000.2
8000.3
8001.1
8001.2
8002.1
8003.1
8004.1
8004.2
8005.1
```

I have to think this is more likely to be the correct output.

If you *do* need to have the first repeat group treated specially, this code could easily be modified to do that, but I would make it very explicit in the code instead of what appears to be an accidental effect of the extra space in front of every value except the first.

Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geary/woykv768/5/).